# How to make a page visible only to users with permission to use the administration theme?

Tags: users, uri

I have created a basic page which I only want to be viewable by people who have access to the administration theme.

I have given the page a path of admin/shipping-help but to my surprise the page is visible to anonymous visitors, nor does the page display in the admin theme.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am a bit confused because when I assign an admin path to a views page, it is always displayed in the admin theme.

Comment: is that working @Paul did you tried below answers ?

Comment: Because of the complications I ended up moving away from the idea of publishing nodes within the admin interface and instead found a workable solution using the collapsible blocks module - https://www.drupal.org/project/collapsiblock For the moment this serves my purposes by allowing me to place help information where needed.

Comment: Based on suggestions here I did succeed with a combination of Themekey and Path Access, but this seemed like a hammer to crack a nut. Collapsiblock will do for now.

Comment: okay got solution good to know :) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

There are some modules that can help with this: like Content Acess, or Node Access

[Node Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess)
[Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access)

Answer (score 0):

For **restricting particular url** or **Basic page** you can go with

this module will suite you best
[path_access](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_access)

if that dont work

Refer this link for  **[Controlling Access to Content Overview](https://www.drupal.org/node/270000)**

hope this helps

Comment: Yes I like path access and may go down this route. Something which displays the node in the admin theme is also needed. As the page title suggests, it is for an internal help system.

Answer (score 0):

A basic page is a node. It will be on the internal `node/%` path. Giving it an alias of `admin/shipping-help` is not going to change that. You need it to be on `admin/...` internal path.

Create a new entry for hook_menu with your admin path and display the node in question:

```
function MODULE_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['admin/shipping-help'] = array(
    'title' => "Shipping Help",
    'page callback' => 'MODULE_shipping_help',
    'access arguments' => array('access administration menu'),
  );

  return $items;
}

function MODULE_shipping_help() {
  $node = node_load(70);
  if ($node) {
    return node_view($node);
  }
}
```

Then set the node in question to unpublished to protect it from unauthorised access from `node/%` path. You can even intercept a request for that path and redirect to the admin path.

Comment: Well I didn't know that I didn't know that :-) So much to learn. Is there a lightweight contrib module which can provide this functionality. Thank you.

Comment: Page Manager and Panels come to mind, though they aren't lightweight